# Issues with Date() when using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, date

I am trying to calculate the difference between two times using JavaScript. It's just basic math but I seem to have some issues with that while using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

If you're wondering why am I applying the `JSON.stringify()` function to the date, it's because I using local storage to store some data on the client side and use it whenever the client lands on my website again ( it's faster that way rather than making more requests to the server ). That data usually updates once in a while ( I'm grabbing the data through API from another website ), so I set up a `data_update` variable and I'm storing it together with the other data.

That way I'm grabbing the stored data from the local storage and check if the difference between `data_update` ( which is a date / time ) and the time / date when the check it's made and see if it's greater than a week / day /etc .

So that is the reason why I'm using the JSON functions. My problem is that when I'm parsing the data from the local storage, the date seems to be different from a `Date()` object.

I'm trying to do the next operation per say :

```
var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date()));

var y = JSON.parse(this.get_local_storage_data(this.data_cache_key)); // the data object stored on local storage

var q = y.data_update; // this is the variable where the Date() was stored

console.log(Math.floor((x-q)/1000));
```

The above will return `null`. Also when I want to see the `Math.floor(x)` result, it returns `null` again.

So what can I do in this situation ? Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: You can avoid aggro like this by using a localStorage wrapper like rhaboo instead of stringify/parse which have many other inaccuracies besides this one.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you look at the output of JSON.stringify for a Date, you'll see that:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date())
```

Results in a string.  JSON does not have a primitive representation of Date objects that JSON.parse will turn back into a Date object automatically.

The Date object's constructor can take a date string, so you can turn those string values back into dates by doing:

```
var x = new Date(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date())));
```

Then the arithmetic will work.

```
x = new Date(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date())))
y = new Date(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date())))
y - x
=> 982
```

Comment: While the JSON specification doesn't define what to do with Dates, as of ECMAScript 2016, ECMA-262 does. Implementations should use [*Date.prototype.toJSON*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tojson), which creates an ISO 8601 string as for *toISOString* (it uses the same method). But you may not have crystal–balled that in 2012… ;-)

Comment: One would expect JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date())) to return a Date object (like with number for example). I cannot see where the current behavior is useful. Any thoughts why isn't the default something like this: 
 `_jsonUTCDateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z$/;

      fromJson(jsonString: string) {        
        return JSON.parse(jsonString, (key, value) => {
          if (typeof value === "string" && this._jsonUTCDateFormat.test(value)) {            
            return this.parseUTCDate(value);
          }
          return value;
        });
      }`

Answer (score 28):

```
JSON.stringify(new Date())
```

returns

> "2013-10-06T15:32:18.605Z"

Thank God is: `Date.prototype.toISOString()`

Comment: Good to know that `JSON.stringify()` uses `Date.toISOString()` behind the scenes. This made my code much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As the recommended answer suggests, the date is simply converted to a string when using `JSON.stringify`.

Another approach that would maybe fit this use case is to store the time in milliseconds using [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

```js
// Date.now() instead of new Date()
const millis = Date.now();

console.log(millis);

// same output as input
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(millis)));
```

That way you can be sure that what goes into `JSON.stringify` comes out the same when using `JSON.parse`.

This also makes it easy to compare dates, if you have two millisecond values, using `<` and `>`.

Plus you can convert the milliseconds to a date at any time (usually before you render it to the user):

```js
const millis = Date.now();

console.log(millis);

console.log(new Date(millis));
```

NOTE: using milliseconds as your date representation is usually not recommended, at least not in your database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48974248/10551293.