# JS: Bug converting string to Date

Tags: javascript, android, json, samsung-mobile

I am converting a Data Object to JSON and back with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

This works great, on all devices but on **Samsung Galaxy SII** where for the line:

```
console.log(jsonObj.gebDat+"::"+new Date(jsonObj.gebDat));
```

I get the output:

> 1973-07-01T10:49:25.134Z::Invalid Date

I am implementing this exactly like at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11491993/386738), and it works for most devices, am I doing something wrong??

**UPDATE**

to clarify the question. I create a String calling

```
var stringToSave = JSON.stringify({gebDat: dataclass.gebDat, <here are some more variables>});
```

then I save it. Later, I load the string and parse it with

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(stringToSave);
```

then, I try to set my date again (calling a log just before that line) with

```
console.log(jsonObj.gebDat+"::"+new Date(jsonObj.gebDat));
this.gebDat = new Date(jsonObj.gebDat);
```

The log gives me the invalid date as shown above, and when I represent the Date it displays `NaN.NaN.NaN` instead of the expected `01.07.1973`

Comment: Is your Galaxy SII on the same Android version than your other devices?

Comment: @Bigood No, the Galaxy SII is on Android version 2.3.3.

Comment: Do you handle dates in different timezones? Other wise try the constructor format `new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])`

Comment: What is `jsonObj.gebDat`? A string? A Date object?

Comment: @Xotic750 `jsonObj.gebDat` is a string containing "1973-07-01T10:49:25.134Z" in this case. The string is generated using `JSON.stringify` over a variable of type `Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Date string formats are implementation dependent. It is always recommended to use timestamps when you save dates.

```
var timestamp = Date.parse( new Date() );//1372675910000
```

Now you can use the saved timestamps to recreate the date later

```
var date = new Date(1372675910000);//Mon Jul 01 2013 16:21:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

2.For a simple transition from your current solution, in case you dont handle different timezones,

```
var dateString = jsonObj.getDat.substring(0,23);
var datePart = dateString.split('T')[0].split('-');
var timePart = dateString.split('T')[1].split(/[:.]/);
var DateOj = new Date(datePart[0], datePart[1], datePart[2], timePart[0], timePart[1], timePart[2]);
```

Let me clarify 1, with reference to your update.

```
var stringToSave = JSON.stringify({gebDat: Date.parse(dataclass.gebDat), <here are some more variables>});

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(stringToSave);

console.log('timestamp :' + jsonObj.gebDat);//1372680083000
console.log(new Date(jsonObj.gebDat));//Mon Jul 01 2013 17:31:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: [Date.parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) uses a string as parameter. I think using it with a Date parameter would not be a great idea.

Comment: The suggession was to store `jsonObj.getDat` as timestamp. Then use that timestamp in date constructor.

Comment: With `JSON.stringify` the method [toJSON()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp) is automatically called. It should work as good as a timestamp since it uses ISO-8601 standards.

Comment: It works with the timestamp. I guess that's because of a bug in the contructor of Date in Android 2.3.3 that was corrected later...

Comment: Yes, thay might have missed the rfc and iso recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

you need send string and you send callback.

try:

```
console.log(jsonObj.gebDat+"::"+new Date(jsonObj.gebDat()));
```