# Difference between converting date into string with toISOString() and JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, string, function, performance, date

I researched about converting `date` into `string` in *ISO* format, and I found two methods to do that giving me the same result `'2022-07-29T06:46:54.085Z'`:

1. `(new Date()).toISOString()`
2. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date()))`

**Question:**

- Does `JS` make two approaches/algorithms of converting date or just one function code just call on different object `JSON` or `Date`, If So Which one is the best to use?

Comment: json stringfy gives extra quotes

Comment: edited with `JSON.parse` removes those extra quotes!

Comment: I bet JSON.stringify calls toISOString somewhere behind the curtain. Use the one that explicitly does what you want: toISOString.

Comment: guess this is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491938/issues-with-date-when-using-json-stringify-and-json-parse#comment75700467_19210578. some here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date()))` is just the same as `new Date().toJSON()`. And in the [docs for that method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) we can see

> Calling `toJSON()` returns a string (using [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)) representing the `Date` object's value.

So they're having exactly the same result, calling `toISOString()` directly is just much more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **less code, easier to maintain**

So, `new Date().toISOString()` is simplest way to return string in ISO format.

Regarding question:

No. The output is the same, because of `JSON.stringify` logic underneath that returns:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date())
'"2022-07-29T18:58:14.411Z"'
```

Because:

> The instances of Date implement the toJSON() function by returning a string (the same as date.toISOString()). Thus, they are treated as strings.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
(new Date).toJSON()
'2022-07-29T18:58:14.411Z'
```

Comment: If "simple" means less code, then `new Date().toJSON()` is less to type and produces an identical result. ;-)

Comment: @RobG why so? `'new Date().toJSON()'.length` => 19 `'(new Date).toJSON()'.length` => 19 - no difference ;)

Comment: You suggested using `new Date().toISOString()`, which is longer. `(new Date).toJSON()` relies on a quirk of ECMAScript constructors that is rarely used in practice, so not a good idea—IMHO of course. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If an object passed to [*JSON.stringify*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-json.stringify) has a *toJSON* method, then it's used to set the value within the JSON text (see [*SerializeJSONProperty* step 2.b](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-serializejsonproperty)).

*Date* instances have a [*toJSON*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tojson) method that is defined as returning the same value as [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

I.e.

```
date.toJSON() === date.toISOString()
```

by design.